# Can you use objects in SQL like you can in R for strings/dates to avoid typing the information each time?

Tags: sql, r, arrays, date, object

I'm new to SQL, and I'm trying to determine if you can define objects in it like you can in R. For instance, I have a query where I need to make sure the date is the same in each table.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1 AS t1
WHERE t1.date = '2021-02-14'
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.date = '2021-02-14';
```

I want to run this query over and over, but it's cumbersome to change the date each time and opens the chance for typos. If this were R, I could do something like:

```
my_date <- '2021-02-14'

SELECT *
FROM table_1 AS t1
WHERE t1.date = my_date
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.date = my_date;
```

And only have to change it in one place. Is something like this possible in SQL? If not, what would you recommend as the easiest way to avoid copy-and-pasting or using Control + F.

Currently, my main focus is on dates, but if you have a solution that would work for any data type (i.e., a number value that's used in many WHERE statements), that'd be awesome.

Comment: Which dbms? In postgres, you can set a variable like this: set @my_date = '03/01/2015';   and then reference in the query such as: where buy_date > to_date('@my_date', 'mm/dd/yyyy');

Comment: @Isolated, I'm not sure what dbms we're using--how would one find that out? I did try that code below but it didn't recognize the @ my_date argument and failed to execute

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I'm trying to run the query just in SQL not in R. Is there a way to do what you proposed but just in a SQL query without having to run the query in R?

Comment: For the sql statement shown try: `SELECT *
FROM table_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id and t1.date = t2.date and t1.date = '2014-02-14' `

Answer (score 1):

Update:

A coworker shared with me his solution that works and is extendable beyond dates. You make a common-table expression (CTE) at the start of your query that contains your filters. Then, plug it in throughout, so you only need to change it in one place. For instance:

```
WITH filt AS (
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('2021-02-14')
    ) AS tbl (date_filter)
)

SELECT
    *
FROM table_1
WHERE
    date IN (
        SELECT
            date_filter
        FROM filt
    )
```

Comment: or maybe `with filt as (select '2014-02-14' as date) select t1.* from table_1 t1, filt where t1.date = filt.date`